# Deserializing json to pojo where json field has different data types

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I'm trying to deserialize json to java pojo and I can't wrap my head around how should I begin to create a java object that could be used to deserialize json like this:

```
{
    "links": [],
    "version": 2,
    "executionState": "completed",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "identifier",
            "value": "2411"
        },
        {
            "name": "segment",
            "value": "COMPLEX"
        },
        {
            "name": "rules",
            "value": [
                {
                    "metadata": [
                        {
                            "ID": "int"
                        },
                        {
                            "NAME": "string"
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "data": [
                        [
                            2,
                            "S1"
                        ],
                        [
                            21,
                            "S6"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm working with jackson and looking to use something like this:
MyPojo response = mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyPojo.class)

The biggest struggle is those "value" elements, where some fields contain simple String and in other cases have an array of elements

I've tried to create an abstract class for the element "value", and then 2 more classes that would extend abstract class. But that didn't work

Comment: Do you have control over the source of the JSON? Just because defining one element which could be of type `String` or of type `Array<Object>` is really bad practice. You should try to get a JSON with a good schema instead.

Comment: Could you share your POJO?

Comment: @McPringle, unfortunately I don't have any control over JSON

Comment: @JoseA.Matarán, I ended up using POJO that is identical to the one that josejuan proposed. Small difference was that instead of class Outputs2ItemMeta I used Map<String, String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is create a custom type resolver:

```
static class Outputs {
    public String name;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = OutputsDeserializer.class)
    public OutputsValue value;
}

static abstract class OutputsValue {

}

@AllArgsConstructor
static class Outputs1 extends OutputsValue {
    public String value;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
static class Outputs2 extends OutputsValue {
    public List<Outputs2Item> value;
}

static class OutputsDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<OutputsValue> {

    @Override
    public OutputsValue deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
        if (node.getNodeType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("STRING"))
            return new Outputs1(codec.treeToValue(node, String.class));
        List<Outputs2Item> xs = new ArrayList<>();
        node.elements().forEachRemaining(e -> {
            try {
                xs.add(codec.treeToValue(e, Outputs2Item.class));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return new Outputs2(xs);
    }
}

static class Outputs2Item {
    public List<Outputs2ItemMeta> metadata;
    public List<Object /* integer | string */ > data;
}

static class Outputs2ItemMeta {
    public String ID;
    public String NAME;
}

static class Pojo {
    public List<String> links;
    public int version;
    public String executionState;
    public List<Outputs> outputs;
}
```

running with

```
final Pojo o = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("/home/josejuan/tmp/z.json"), Pojo.class);
```

the object contains all required values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson to parse the JSON into a JsonNode instance and create the POJOs yourself, depending on the type of the value element:

```
final var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
final var jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
```

Then you can use the instance methods provided by `JsonNode` to check the values and types and create the corresponding Java objects.